# Every Bitcoin qt transaction I send comes up uncomfirmed?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I tried so many test transactions ranging from a couple of cents to 3 dollars to send to my new online wallets. For some reason it never gets confirmed even though I put a good miners fee (I have tried .00007 and even higher). I tried some of those transactions 4 months ago and still they have not even gone through. If someone can help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

With the information you provider, the most likely answer is one of two things:

Your fee may be too low. Based on [current fees](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/) the fee you paid may not be enough. Keep in mind that the fees [displayed here](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/) are calculated per byte so if your transaction is particularly large (in bytes not in BTC value) then you will need a larger fee.

Another possibility is that your transaction includes inputs that are themselves unconfirmed. This question will provide you with more details, with the [child-pays-per-parent](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/45971/37927) answer providing a possible solution if this was your problem.